# How to access Spring MVC/Webflow objects when debugging JSP page?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to debug a JSP page which is powered by Spring Webflow 2.3.2.   I have a webflow view state defined as:

```
<view-state id="someInfo" model="someInfo" view="someInfo">
```

Everything works but when I try to step into someInfo.jsp (I am using IntelliJ) and debug, I cannot identify how to find the "model" object and other page attributes.   They don't appear to be in the pageContext, or any other available object that I can find.   The objects I have a choice of in the debugger are:

```
this
request
response
out
_jspx_out
_jspx_page_context
pageContext
```

and a bunch of Spring objects attached to individual tags.

Where are passed-in attributes hidden in this hierarchy?

Comment: If I remember correctly, model stuffs are passed in the context objects, so if I were you, I try to find things there...